# Page not rendered properly on browser called Internet (LG)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, cross-browser, lg

I built a website in Rails and it is rendered properly on most major browsers, on computer and phone. However, on my phone (an LG G3) which has a browser called Internet (version 5.2.34b13) I can't open navbar, I can't sign up and some other small features are not there. On the same phone it works fine with Chrome.

Has anybody had any similar problems? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Jello Al-Josh!

It sounds to me like it is a cross-browser issue and has nothing to do with Rails. I'd recommend you to use the Autoprefixer gem ( https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails ) to sort out CSS vendor prefixes issues.